# How can I write additional test information to the screen during a testrun?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to output some additional information about a test run that I can quickly visually review. It doesn't affect the outcome of the test.

I am familiar with `Assert.Inconclusive(String)` but I want the test to pass/fail on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use `TestContext.WriteLine()` to write information about the test run.

This information will appear under the heading "Additional Information" in the test run results window.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you would do well to use Trace.Write() to put out informational messages before calling your Assert methods.  This is really a matter of preference, but Trace.Write() seems like the tool for that job.